# Creating a Drawable from a file and putting it into a SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-resources

I've created my own ListView to add an image.  Nothing special, you can find XML here: http://pastebin.com/XBq2nNCd

I read data from a downloaded JSON and put it into the ListView this way:

```
//Getting data from JSONManager
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listMovies = this.jsonManager.retrieveMovieList();
maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewmovies);
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listMovies, R.layout.listviewmovies_layout,
            new String[] {"image", "title", "summary"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.titre, R.id.description});
maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

So, *listMovies* contains data like this:

```
movie.put("title", movieData.getString("title"));
movie.put("summary", movieData.getString("summary"));
movie.put("image", R.drawable.default_picture_48_48);
```

Data is processed into an other class and is retrieved by the activity.
This code works fine. Perfect!

But my goal is to use local images (previously downloaded) instead of *R.drawable* (which would be used as fallback).
And there is my problem… I'm just unable to set a local image instead of a *R.drawable*.

For the moment, I've tried this code:
(As you can see, pictures are located in a subdir called… «pictures» :P )

```
//Setting file path into a File object
File image = new File(this.context.getDir("pictures", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)+"/"+movieData.getString("image_name"));
if(image.exists()) {
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(image.getPath());
    movie.put("image", d);
}
else
    movie.put("image", R.drawable.default_picture_48_48);
```

And this code doesn't work.  My file **exists** (I've checked with the debugger and `if(image.exists())` is processed) but I got this error:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@14c0daa: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

So…
My picture exist…
… but it doesn't show. :(

What's wrong with this code?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you having permission of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions ? If you are testing on marshmallow or higher use runtime permission . (here is the link )https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I'm using internal storage, not external.  So I shouldn't need any permission.  I can read and process a JSON file stored in internal storage without any problem.  I've tried adding `checkSelfPermission` but problem remain the same.